# T-SQL select into temp table does not have correct result

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables, row-number, select-into

-- This Result Is Right and work correctly:

```
SELECT AutoId, Name,[Group],[Priority], SUMCalculatedPercent
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT *,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
 (
    PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY SUMCalculatedPercent DESC,[Priority]
 ) 
 AS ranker 
 FROM #GroupMasterNameChoose
)Z
WHERE ranker = 1
ORDER BY Z.SUMCalculatedPercent DESC,Z.[Priority]
```

---

-- This Result Is Wrong :

```
SELECT AutoId, Name,[Group],[Priority], SUMCalculatedPercent
INTO #GroupOwner
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT *,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
 (
    PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY SUMCalculatedPercent DESC,[Priority]
 ) 
 AS ranker 
 FROM #GroupMasterNameChoose
)Z
WHERE ranker = 1
ORDER BY Z.SUMCalculatedPercent DESC,Z.[Priority]
```

--
Problem : I Need Store My Right Result To Temp Table

Comment: on what basis result is wrong can you explain clearly

Comment: I don't think the `ORDER BY` clause in the second query has any meaning or purpose.

Comment: What error message do you get here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove **ORDER BY Z.SUMCalculatedPercent DESC,Z.[Priority]**